# How to add active class in bootstrap with flask?

Tags: javascript, flask

my navbar is:

```
<ul class="nav">
     
      <li  class="nav-item  ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#SubMenu">
          <span class="menu-title">Details</span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="SubMenu">
          <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('Details') }}">Upload Details</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

My code runs on flask on the server side, I want to dynamically add active class on the `<li class="nav-item>`, when `<a class="nav link">` is selected, I tried various solutions provided on SO, but none is working, if someone could help me figure out, whats happening wrong?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this menu will be there in all in all the pages. so better create a base file.

Just assume you are in Upload Details page `{{ url_for('Details') }}`.

In that page, extend this base template, and set a `active_page` variable.

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}
{% set active_page = 'upload_page' %}
...
```

In you `base.html`

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li  class="nav-item {{ 'active' if active_page=='upload_page' else ''}}">
```